# yii2 insert input with the same name to database?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i am trying to insert data in a database in yii2 but i have like 3 input with the same name .
And when i try to insert in to the data base it just insert the value of the last input.

this is my controller

```
public function actionCompose_vote()
{
    $topic= new Topic(); 
    if ($topic->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $topic->load($_POST);
        $topic->save();
        return $this->refresh();
    }
    return $this->render('compose_vote');
}
```

This is the view

```
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use app\models\MyProfile;
use app\models\LikeDiscussion;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\Topic;
use common\models\Comment;
use common\models\Users;
use common\models\Candidate;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <input type="name"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">
    <input type="name"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">
    <input type="name"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic"> 
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I also tried to puting the values in a foreach loop

```
foreach ($_POST['Topic[topic]'] as $top) {
    $top => $topic;
}
```

But it gives error that variable "Topic[topic]" does not exist.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to accomplish? It is not quite clear to me. If you submit 3 times the same attribute and make the model load the `$_POST`, it will get only the last result.

Comment: different details in each input i want to insert all three to database

Comment: Why exactly you have 3 same names? You should change that (make minor changes) and you won't have any problems then.

Comment: What do you want to do!!!??three input with same attributes even id!

Answer (score 1):

Please, read the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html). What is the point of adding inputs with pure html when we can use the [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html) for that? Plus, you are missing all the validation doing that way.

And if you have a form that saves multiple values at once, I strongly recommend you to create another model just for this form. Like this:

```
class ModelForm extends \yii\base\Model
{
    public $attribute;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['attribute'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'attribute' => 'Friendly Name',
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($modelForm, 'attribute[]') ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelForm, 'attribute[]') ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelForm, 'attribute[]') ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelForm, 'attribute[]') ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Adding the `[]` will make sure the `$_POST` value will be an array. Then you can get this array and make a loop in your controller to try to save a new instance of your Model:

```
$modelForm = new ModelForm();

if ($modelForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    foreach ($modelForm->attribute as $attribute) {
        $model = new Model(['attribute' => $attribute]); // load each information in your desired model->attribute

        if (!$model->save()) {
            var_dump($model->getErrors()); // verify each Model could be saved and, if not, handle the error.
            return;
        }
    }

    return $this->refresh();
}

return $this->render('compose_vote', ['modelForm' => $modelForm]);
```